# how to visualize lattice with periodic, helical, etc. boundary conditions?

Tags: networking, visualization

I am trying to write a special hexagonal lattice generator, with several kinds of boundary conditions, such as helical BC, periodic BC, and I find it hard to verify whether it works correctly. I tried to draw them using 2-dimensional network drawing (using networkx) and as I expected, it was a total mess. Right now I have to work out the adjacency matrix beforehand and verify the generated network with the calculated adjacency matrix. It's fine with the regular lattice, but if I introduce some random perturbation on the lattice, this approach is very tiresome. It would be a lot easier if I could see the network drawn correctly.

Is it possible to correctly visualize lattice with various boundary conditions? Or in other software tools? Is there a convenient way to test this kind of network generator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly straightforward - if blunt - tool for visualization would be gnuplot, assuming you have the 3d coordinates of each point. Gnuplot will draw a separate line for each block separated by a newline, so this

```
0  1  0
0  1  1

0  1  0
0  2  0
```

would draw 2 lines, from (0,1,0) to the two points (0,1,1) and (0,2,0), if you issue the command

```
splot 'somefile' with lines
```

The only problem will be that if you have 3 points all along some line, and you plot a line AC instead of AB and BC, it won't be clear.

You will, however, be able to drag to rotate the 3d plot, which should help your inspection.

Comment: Interesting solution. But in this case, one will have to work out the 3d coordinates of the network. For example, if we have a square lattice with periodic boundary conditions, we will have to calculate how the nodes in the network spread on the surface of a torus.